# Changing the file association of todoo or alternatively completely disable it

Tags: files, start-up

I am using emacs on a debian system and have installed emacs-goodies-el. One of the many things in there is `todoo` which registers itself in `auto-mode-alist` for all files ending in `TODO`.

This particular association is in the way and I would like to either get rid of `todoo` or just change the entry in the `auto-mode-alist`.

I tried to find a switch in `customize-group emacs-goodies-el` but there seems to be nothing.

I've got a few incantations in a file in `~/.emacs.d` and could add to those, but fiddling with with `auto-mode-alist` seems a bit daunting. The entry I need to get rid of is

```
("TODO\\'" . todoo-mode)
```

So if anyone knows off-hand how to easily disable `todoo` in `emacs-goodies-el`, let me know. Alternatively a hint how to remove this element from the alist or just define a different file pattern would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to remove the entry.

```
(setq auto-mode-alist  (rassq-delete-all 'todoo-mode auto-mode-alist))
```

I'm not sure there's a specialized way to remove entry of `auto-mode-alist`.

Answer (score 0):

Newer entries take priority over older ones, so you could just do

```el
(push '("TODO\\'" . text-mode) auto-mode-alist)
```